# Angular html select issue

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

As you can see from the links below, when loading the page the first time, the first select uses its first option to display "select street". Then I select a city and the first select shows the corresponding streets.

The issue is, when I choose one street and then click on another city, the select tag which displays the streets, does not show the "Select street" option, but the first index (if you use the dropdown you will see the option "Select street").
How can I make it display "Select street" (first option) each time I change the city option?

editor :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwqst6

html url : https://angular-hwqst6.stackblitz.io

Comment: You bind the select boxes to a model, and you change the model: https://angular.io/guide/forms. Or you use a reactive form, and you change the value of the form control bound to the select: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: links to a 3rd party code repository are not a replacement for a [mcve] **in the question body**.  You will get more useful responses if you [edit] your question and add code showing the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Doesn't change anything with reactive forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you did some change on your demo, I can't keep the city selected now. Please refer to the following code:

```
onCitySelected(){
    this.retrievedStreets.length = 0;
    this.retrievedStreets = Object.assign(this.retrievedStreets, this.myObj[this.form.value.city].streets);
    this.form.patchValue({street: null});
}
//you can remove the method lookupStreets
```

Comment: Issue is after selecting a street and then changing the city, the default option "select street" does not appear as placeholder like in the beginning

Comment: @YoussefHarkati try it, it is ok on your demo.